# How much should I know before jumping into Raven's Home?

Tags: suggested-order, ravens-home, thats-so-raven, cory-in-the-house

Recently I got to know that *That's So Raven* had a newer spinoff called *Raven's Home*. But I remember I didn't finish *That's So Raven* and barely know about *Cory in the House*.

So I wanted to know how much self-contained *Raven's Home* is. Can I just watch it straight forward with the basic knowledge of *That's So Raven*? Or do I need to finish the previous both shows first?

<sub>Note: I have seen most of *That's So Raven*, except the last seasons when she starts working.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a set of three episodes in the second season of *Raven's Home* where Raven meets Dr. Sleevemore again.  Raven meet Dr. Sleevemore in one episode in the first season and two episodes of the third season of *That's So Raven*.

[Why doesn't Raven tell Ben about Dr Sleevemore et al?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/why-doesnt-raven-tell-ben-about-dr-sleevemore-et-al)[1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/why-doesnt-raven-tell-ben-about-dr-sleevemore-et-al)

Raven's ex-husband, a former boyfriend from *That's So Raven*, appears in several episodes.

And Raven's father Victor shows up in another episode episode in the second season.

And as far as I can remember those are the main connections between *That's So Raven* and *Raven's Home* so far.

Answer (score 0):

Update: With *Raven's Home s5*, there may be some episodes of *Cory in the House* needed to understand a few references in *Raven's Home s5*. But I suspect Raven's Home s5 will be mostly self-contained.