# How much should I know before jumping into The Fairly OddParents: Fairly Odder?

Tags: suggested-order, the-fairly-oddparents, fairly-odder

Recently I got to know that *The Fairly OddParents* had a newer spinoff called *The Fairly OddParents: Fairly Odder*. But I didn't watch the newer seasons of *The Fairly OddParents* and have seen only 1 of the *live action The Fairly OddParents*.

So I wanted to know how much self-contained *The Fairly OddParents: Fairly Odder* is. Well, it probably is going to be pretty self-contained for new viewers much like [the movies for Hey Arnold! or Veronica Mars](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66540/whats-up-with-anime-movies-that-are-really-sequels-to-series-instead-of-adaptat) or [the movies of Haruhi Suzumiya or The Quintessential Quintuplets (sort of)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66540/whats-up-with-anime-movies-that-are-really-sequels-to-series-instead-of-adaptat) or the spin-off [Raven's Home](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101918/how-much-should-i-know-before-jumping-into-ravens-home) of *That's So Raven*.

I suspect I can watch Fairly Odder straight forward with the basic knowledge of *The Fairly OddParents*, but **are there some references made to the newer seasons of the original FOP or the live action?**